# How to add subitem with new item in asp.net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, view

I have simple code first model (image: https://ufile.io/7c52a)

I have a problem, when I want to add a new bill. When I add a new bill, I also want to add products on that bill (insert data into Pr_bi table).

My bill entity:

```
public class Bill : Entity
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product_Bill> Product_Bill { get; set; }
}
```

My product entity:

```
public class Product : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product_Bill> Product_Bill { get; set; }
}
```

My pr_bi entity:

```
public class Product_Bill : Entity
{
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public virtual Bill Bill { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

I create create view model like that:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Bill", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" })){
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID)
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Bill number:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Number, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Payed:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Payed)
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Customer:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Customer.ID, ViewData["Customers"] as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-6"><input type="submit" value="Shrani" class="btn btn-default" /></div>
</div>}
```

How can I add product on that bill inside that create view for a bill?

What do I have and what I like:
[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ogFJ.png)

Thank you and have a nice day!

Comment: please add your  UI screen do you want to display?

Comment: I've added what I have and what I want to have